# From specific dates add future random dates and save results in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a data frame in which one of the columns contained dates. I want to add a new column with random future dates.

A representative dataframe

```
data = {'Dates': ['2021-01-01','2021-01-08','2021-01-02']}
        
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Dates'])
```

In the original data frame, Date have been created with this code

```
df['Date'] = random_dates(start=pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01'), 
                                             end=pd.to_datetime('2021-01-31'), size=X)
```

What I have tried unlike

```
for idx, value in df.iloc[:,3].iteritems(): # Bacause in my real df, date is the 4th column
    df.loc[idx, ['discharge_date']] = df.loc[idx, ['Date']] + timedelta(days=random.randint(3, 50)) # The new date must be something between +3 to +50 days from the column date
```

What I got with this code is a column with Na.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
import random
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', end='1/08/2021')})
df['future'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x + datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(3, 50)))


        Date     future
0 2021-01-01 2021-01-18
1 2021-01-02 2021-01-09
2 2021-01-03 2021-02-13
3 2021-01-04 2021-01-21
4 2021-01-05 2021-01-11
5 2021-01-06 2021-01-30
6 2021-01-07 2021-01-28
7 2021-01-08 2021-02-13
```